# async function does not return json object

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

```
public async validateToken(req, res): Promise<any> {

    const token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1] || req.params.token;
    await this.redisClient.SISMEMBER("tokenBlackListSet", token, function(
        err,
        data
      ) {
        if (data) { // here i get data=1 as token is present in tokenBlackListSet
          return {  // so this  should be returned as json
            status: 400,
            error: "Invalid Token"
          };
        }
      });

}



// in other async function

const response = await validateToken(req,res);

console.log(response) // returned value is always undefined
```

Comment: `validateToken` has no `return` statement

Comment: what if i want to return from redisClient.SISMEMBER's callback function

Comment: Then you need to return a Promise that you resolve in your callback (with your object as argument in the resolve method call)

Comment: i changed as you suggested , but still it is not working


return await this.redisClient.SISMEMBER(
        "tokenBlackListSet",
        token,
        function(err, data) {
          if (data) {
            return new Promise(resolve =>
              resolve({
                status: 400,
                error: "Invalid Token"
              })
            );
          }
        }
      );

Comment: I have written an answer, I hope it can help you.

Comment: @pradeepdesai Creating the promise inside of the callback won't help. You need to wrap your whole function inside a promise and resolve the value in your callback.

Comment: @ Jeffrey & Seblor : yes it solved my problem , thanks you friends :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the `SISMEMBER` method return a boolean, and not the value returned by the callback, you can return a new Promise that you resolve in the callback :

```
public async validateToken(req, res): Promise<any> {

  const token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1] || req.params.token;

  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { // Here I create a new Promise that will resolve (or reject) when your callback is called
    this.redisClient.SISMEMBER("tokenBlackListSet", token, function(
      err,
      data
    ) {
      if (err) { // If there is an error, we reject the promise
        reject(err);
      }
      else if (data) { // If you have some data, the promise will resolve with the object
        resolve({
          status: 400,
          error: "Invalid Token"
        });
      }
    });

  }

}
```

Notice I removed the `await` since it is now redundant with the fact that we return a promise already.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will work

```
public async validateToken(req, res): Promise<any> {

const token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1] || req.params.token;
return await this.redisClient.SISMEMBER("tokenBlackListSet", token, (err,data)=> {
    if (err) { throw new Error(err) }
    else return { status: 400,error: "Invalid Token"};
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Same as Radu's answer : Are you sure SISMEMBER will resolve with the returned value from the callback ?

Comment: looks like `await` here is redundant.

Comment: `this.redisClient.SISMEMBER` returns a promise that can be resolved by a caller of `validateToken` function.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Promise` object, and resolve that from inside the callback

```
public async validateToken(req, res): Promise<any> {

 let resCallback, rejCallback

 const returnPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resCallback = resolve
    refCallback = reject
 })

 const token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1] || req.params.token;
 await this.redisClient.SISMEMBER("tokenBlackListSet", token, function(
    err,
    data
  ) {
    if (data) { // here i get data=1 as token is present in tokenBlackListSet
      resCallback({  // so this  should be returned as json
        status: 400,
        error: "Invalid Token"
      });
    }
  });

 return retPromise
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `SISMEMBER` will resolve with the returned value from the callback ?

Comment: i need to return json based on 'data' variable's value in callback function

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that the `this.redisClient.SISMEMBER` will wrap your callback result as a promise. If it would be case, you wouldn't be one here to ask the question.

Your result is lost in the void at the moment as the callback result is not passed as a return value.

Wrap the function into a promise and resolve or reject it when the callback is invoked by your library:

```
async function getSISMember() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.redisClient.SISMEMBER("tokenBlackListSet", token, function(
      err,
      data
    ) {
      if (err) return reject(err);  // Throw an error if an error is passed to callback
      if (data) { // Return the object you want to return by resolving the promise
        resolve({
          status: 400,
          error: "Invalid Token"
        });
      }
    });
  })
}
```

`await getSISMember()` should now either error or give you the JSON response

Comment: Checkout @Seblor's answer as he implemented the function as a whole. I just ensured the result of your function would be resolved into a promise, which he did too.